# How do I treat a derivative at the denominator?

Tags: calculus

I am sure there is a similar question but I don't know how to phrase it, so I cannot find it. I'm searching for some intuition or direction to material of how to treat an expression like this:
$$
\frac{1}{1 + \partial_x}f(x) 
$$
or more in general (with $L$ some operator)
$$
\frac{1}{1 + L}f(x). 
$$
My first guess would be expanding it with power series, but maybe there are some other methods?

Answer (score 5):

> how to treat an expression like this:
> $$
> \frac{1}{1 + \partial_x}f(x) 
> $$
> or more in general (with $L$ some operator)
> $$
> \frac{1}{1 + L}f(x) 
> $$

In Physics (and other fields) we often call the inverse of a differential operator a ["Green's function."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function)

Suppose you are interested in your first example:
$$
\frac{1}{1+\partial_x}\;,
$$

You can seek a function of two variables $G(x,x')$ such that:
$$
(1+\partial_x)G(x,x') = \delta(x - x')\;,
$$
where $\delta(x - x')$ is a Dirac delta function.

As you can see by pursuing the Wikipedia link provided above, this is a well-known technique. But, in short, the function $G(x, x')$ is effectively the inverse you are looking for, since if you determine $G(x,x')$ then you can always solve an equation like:
$$
(1+\partial_x)f(x) = h(x)\;, 
$$
since you can write down a solution immediately as:
$$
f(x) = \int dx' G(x,x')h(x')\;.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Usually, just put to the other side, whenever that expression is equal to something else. As an example:

$$a(x) = \frac{1}{1+\partial_x} f(x) \qquad \rightarrow \qquad f(x) = \left(1 + \partial_x \right) a(x) = a(x) + \partial_x a(x) \ .$$

If you provide some more details, maybe it's possible to provide better answers.

Comment: thank you @basics but what if that's not an option?

Comment: I guess you need to keep computations in the "transformed domain" and treat derivatives as a linear operator. If you add some more details about what you're doing, maybe someone can help you more

Comment: @LowFieldTheory Why is it not an option?

Comment: @Ghoster I added "what if" because the topic may be more general than just the situation of an equation. What if for example `a(x)` in the example is the unknown function and `f(x)` is the known function?

Comment: @LowFieldTheory You solve the differential equation for $a(x)$.

Comment: @Ghoster well that makes sense, I think I got lost in the abstraction while writing here.